# TypeScript kendoTreeView change / select class method callback

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript

I've been searching around to find why Kendo callbacks are not working with TypeScript but I couldn't find something useful.

So my question is how can kendo use class method as a callback?
Ex:

```
    $("#ipt_tree").kendoTreeView(
    {
        dataSpriteCssClassField: "sprite",
        dataSource: data,
        template: "<span data-oid='#= item.oid#'>#= item.text#</span>",
        //change: this.Tree_Item_Selected,      //doens't get even called
        //change: ( item: any ): void =>        //'this' is not 'this' of the class
        //{
        //  this.Tree_Item_Selected( item );
        //}
        change: function( item: any )           //using compiler this variable
        {
            _this.Tree_Item_Selected( item );
        }
    });
```

The only solution I've found is to use the _this variable that compiler makes.

Now for the jquery the method callbacks work perfectly.

```
    $( "#ipb_aci_button_edit" ).show().on( "click", this.Info_OnClick_Edit );
    private Info_OnClick_Edit = (): void =>
    {
    //'this' is correct
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the current version of TypeScript (1.0RC), you create a class:

```
class Demo {
    private Tree_Item_Selected(item:any) { }

    public Create_Tree(data:any) {
        var kendoSettings = {
            dataSpriteCssClassField: "sprite",
            dataSource: data,
            template: "<span>#= item.text#</span>",
            change: ( item: any ): void =>        
            {
                this.Tree_Item_Selected( item );
            },
            change2: function( item: any )        
            {
                _this.Tree_Item_Selected( item );
            }                                   
        };              
    }   
}
```

And compile that to JavaScript, the functions `change` and `change2` in the example code both produce the exact same code block:

```
change: function (item) {
    _this.Tree_Item_Selected(item);
},
change2: function (item) {
    _this.Tree_Item_Selected(item);
}
```

The only difference is that the second one produces an error that `_this` is not found.

In the second example, it's working because it's captured the `this` correctly. However, you might want to consider a different syntax:

```
$( "#ipb_aci_button_edit" ).show().on( "click",
      (e:JQueryEventObject) => { this.Handle_Info_OnClick_Edit(e) } );

private Handle_Info_OnClick_Edit(e:JQueryEventObject): void 
{
    // 'this' is correct as it was captured by the event handler code
}
```

Comment: Thanks.

I've been messing around a little more and the second 'change:' option does work. The problem was that I had a left over function() definition one level up and that caused that this was not properly propagated through the calls. Sometimes it's good to inspect the generated JS too. :)

Re-edit:
Now that I've fixed the upper level the 'change: this.Tree_Item_Selected' option works properly too.